# Find the values of one-digit natural number N for which $\sqrt{4+5N}-\sqrt{7+2N}$ is rational

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I did find the answer but I was wondering whether there would be a better method. I started off by stating that for $\sqrt{4+5N}-\sqrt{7+2N}$ to be rational, $4+5N$ and $7+2N$ must be perfect squares.

Then, let $4+5N=k^2$, where $k$ is an integer.

$N=\frac{k^{2}-4}{5}$

Since $N$ must be a natural number, $k^2-4$ must be divisible by $5$. So, $k^2$ must be a number that ends with the digit $4$ or $9$.

$\therefore k^2=9, 49, 64, 169, \dots$ any $k$ that ends with the digits $3$, $7$ or $8$, so $N=1, 9, 12, \dots$

Then, let $7+2N=t^2$, where $t$ is an integer.

$N=\frac{t^2-7}{2}$

$t^2-7$ must be even, so $t^2$ must be odd,  $\therefore t$ must be odd.

$t^2=9, 25, 49, 81, \dots$, so $N=1, 9, 21, \dots$

$\therefore$ There are two possible one-digit natural number $N$, which are $1$ and $9$.

Is there any other way to solve this question? Because I think my method is a bit tedious and not exactly reproducible for other values of $N$ that is not one-digit.

Comment: Just try all one-digit numbers

Comment: @J.W.Tanner That's... a simpler way, I guess. But I'm looking for a way that is reproducible for, say, if the question asks for three-digit N. Maybe I should have clarified in my question.

Comment: I would try writing $\sqrt{4+5N}-\sqrt{7+2N} = \frac{p}{q},\ $ squaring, rearranging, squaring again to get rid of any square roots and then see if you can deduce anything. I don't know if this leads anywhere though, but I'm not doing the work for you...

Comment: Am I missing something or the requirement that $\sqrt{4+5N}-\sqrt{7+2N}\in\Bbb Q$ for some $N\in\Bbb N$ is equivalent to $\sqrt{4+5N}-\sqrt{7+2N}\in\Bbb N$?

Comment: Do you know modular arithmetic?  Also, there is a flaw in your argument.  Both values don't have to be perfect squares.  They could also be equal.  In this case, you got lucky: they're equal perfect squares.

Comment: @Mike Ah, missed that. Thanks. Then my whole argument fails, dang.

Comment: Looks like a stupid question. Why not $\sqrt{4+5N}-\sqrt{1+8N}$, then at least you have two solutions :-)

Comment: Just means you missed a case.  See user2661923's answer.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Your approach seems to suggest you get $N$ rational when $10p^2+81q^2$ is a square for some integers $p$ and $q$, in which case $N=1+\frac79\left(\frac pq\right)^2 +2p \sqrt{\frac{10}{81}\left(\frac pq\right)^2+1   }$.  All the integers $N$ I have seen so far have $q=1$, so with $10p^2+81$  being  a square  and $N=1+\frac79p^2 +2p \sqrt{\frac{10}{81}p^2+1   }$ being an integer such as when $p=0,2,6,12,54$ (but not $p=28$) giving $N=1,9,57,217,4321$.  I am not sure how fast this approach would be

Comment: @AdamRubinson I tried and I got a really complicated equation which I have no idea how to interpret...

Comment: Well, at least you tried my approach. And trying is the first step to failure...

Comment: After taking another look, it's more complicated than what I was thinking.  How much do you know about solving Diophantine equations?  It looks like this might come down to finding solutions for $a^2-10k^2=135$

Comment: @Mike I haven't gotten there yet; I've just recently started learning number theory. Would you mind explaining how you got $a^2-10k^2=135$?

Answer (score 5):

More than one MathSE reviewer has suggested that the start of my answer could benefit from a re-write.  Seems reasonable, so I re-wrote that part of my answer.

---

> I started off by stating that for $\sqrt{4+5N}-\sqrt{7+2N}$ to be rational, $4+5N$ and $7+2N$ must be perfect squares.

If $~R = A + \sqrt{B}~$ and $~S = C + \sqrt{D},~$ where $~A,B,C,D \in \Bbb{Z^+},$ 
then you could have that $~R - S~$ is rational, without $~B~$ and $~D~$ both being perfect squares.

For example

$$\left(1 + \sqrt{2}\right) - \sqrt{2}$$

is a rational number.

However, the OP (i.e. original poster) is making the more narrow assertion that when $~\displaystyle ~R = \sqrt{4 + 5N} ~$ and $~\displaystyle S = \sqrt{7 + 2N},~$  that $~R - S~$ will be rational if and only if $~(7+2N)~$ and $~(4 + 5N)~$ are perfect squares.

To explore the OP's assertion, consider the following constraint:

$$R = \sqrt{A}, ~S = \sqrt{B}, ~: ~A,B \in \Bbb{Z^+}. \tag1 $$

Under this constraint, when will $(R - S)$ be rational?

One possibility is that

$$\sqrt{4 + 5N} = A = B = \sqrt{7 + 2N} \implies N = 1. \tag2 $$

Ironically, when (2) above applies, and $N=1$, you have that $A,B$ are both perfect squares.

So, exploring the question:

> Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are distinct positive integers where $\sqrt{A} - \sqrt{B}$ is rational.  Does this imply that $A$ and $B$ are each perfect squares?

$$\sqrt{A} - \sqrt{B} = \frac{P}{Q} \implies $$

$$Q\sqrt{A} = Q\sqrt{B} + P \implies $$

$$AQ^2 = BQ^2 + P^2 + 2PQ\sqrt{B} \implies $$

$$AQ^2 - BQ^2 - P^2 = 2PQ\sqrt{B}. \tag3 $$

Since the LHS of (3) above is an integer, the RHS of (3) above is an integer.  There are only two ways that this can happen:

- $B$ is a perfect square. 
  This would imply that $\sqrt{A} =~$ (an integer) + (a rational number), which would imply that $A$ is a perfect square.
- $2PQ\sqrt{B} = 0 \implies P = 0 \implies A = B.$

So, the search for perfect squares is a valid approach.

---

The fact that $N$ is limited to the values in $\{1,2\cdots,9\}$ makes me wonder what the intent of the problem composer is.  If there was some subtle analysis that the student was supposed to use in order to solve the problem, then the problem composer would probably not have specified that $N$ must be a one digit number.

That is, it would simply be too easy for the student to ignore any recently taught Number Theory, which the student was supposed to apply, and simply brute force check each element in $\{1,2,\cdots,9\}.$

One (very speculative) possibility is that the problem composer made a mistake, and intended that $N$ run from $~1~$ through $~99,~$ inclusive, rather than $~1~$ through $~9~$ inclusive.

As presented, the only point to the problem seems to be reinforcing the idea that if $~A,B \in \Bbb{Z^+} ~: A \neq B,~$ then $~\sqrt{A} - \sqrt{B}~$ is rational if and only if $~A~$ and $~B~$ are perfect squares.

Comment: "This is not generally true.  For example 

$$\left(1 + \sqrt{2}\right) - \sqrt{2}$$

is a rational number."

$$$$

This response doesn't make sense to me, as $\ 1+\sqrt{2} \neq \sqrt{M}\ $ for some integer $M.$ So your response isn't a counter-example to OP's statement, right? You then go on to basically confirm that OP's original statement is correct, right? So you should have just said in the comments that he is correct that $A$ and $B$ must be perfect squares, but that he hasn't justified why this is.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Good point, although somewhat arguable.  It was unclear to me what the OP (i.e. original poster) was asserting.  So, I started with the (somewhat inapplicable) example that used $\displaystyle \sqrt{A} = \left[1 + \sqrt{2}\right]$ and (**only then**) narrowed it down to only considering $~A \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$  The idea was to start general and then go specific, to clarify the relevance of the premise that $~A,B \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$

Comment: It may be better if you were to replace "generally" with "a priori" or something like that, noting that the reader took an unjustified logical leap by assuming without proof that $4+5N$ and $7+2N$ must both be perfect squares, as care must be taken to eliminate  $(A+B\sqrt{C})-(D+B\sqrt{C})$; $A,B,C,D$ rational; as a possibility for $\sqrt{4+5N}-\sqrt{7+2N}$. +1 on the answer

Comment: @Mike I have just edited the start of my answer.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I have just edited the start of my answer.

Comment: I think I would be better to start by saying, "OP, you assert that $\ \sqrt{A} - \sqrt{B}\ $ rational implies $A,B$ are both perfect squares, but you didn't justify this, which you should have (otherwise how do you know it's true?). It turns out to be true. One way to show this is like this: ...".

Comment: @AdamRubinson Reasonable.  I do want to prevent confusion.  I edited my answer again.

Answer (score 1):

This would probably be overkill for one-digit solutions, but you implied you might want to find larger solutions.  You already came up with equations $N=\frac{k^2-4}5$ and $N=\frac{t^2-7}2$.  What you didn't do was take the next step of equating them.

$$\frac{k^2-4}5=\frac{t^2-7}2$$
$$2k^2-8=5t^2-35$$
$$5t^2-2k^2=27$$

I believe the next step here is putting it in the appropriate form by eliminating the first coefficient.

$$25t^2-10k^2=135$$

$$a=5t,a^2-10k^2=135$$

I still haven't quite mastered solving problems of this form.  The first step involves finding primitive solutions, which is the part I haven't entirely figured out yet.  Since you've already found 2 values of N, however, you already know 2 solutions.  $N=1$ yields $(a,k)=(15,3)$ and $N=9$ gives $(a,k)=(25,7)$.  I don't know if both solutions are primitive (although I could probably figure that out) or if there are more primitive solutions.

Once you have those, you can use the solutions of the equation $a^2-10k^2=1$ to generate more solutions to the original equation.  You might want to check out https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellEquation.html for more information.

Comment: I believe both solutions are fundamental.  It looks like the smallest solution I generate from $N=1$ gives $a=105,k=33,N=217$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you mind explaining what a 'primitive solution' is? Googling it led me nowhere.

Comment: @Zero Search for Pell's equation instead, and read up how to generate all solutions from the primitive solution.

Comment: @Zero For example, the N=1 solution can generate an infinite number of solutions, but N=9 won't be among them.  The example given in the link is $x^2-10y^2=9$ requires 3 different solutions to generate the rest.